# Windows 10 Pro RDP black screen on host after disconnect

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, black-screen-of-death

When I remote into my computer (Win 10 Pro, Intel 6700, EVGA 960) using the Microsoft RDP server built into Win 10 Pro, everything is fine. It works normally. But when I disconnect and try to use the host computer without the RDP client, as soon as I type in my credentials, the screen goes black, only showing the cursor. The cursor can move around the screen, but it Ctrl+Alt+Delete and any other keyboard shortcuts don't have any effect.

The only solution I have at the moment is to hard restart the computer, where is starts normally and works flawlessly. But that isn't a good solution, as hard powering down a computer repeatedly isn't good for it.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Apparently this is called a black screen of death.

Comment: I assume you have tried logging off the RDP session correctly by clicking Start then Log Off rather than hitting the disconnect cross on the top menu bar?

Comment: Actually, that is the one thing that I haven't tried. I believed that when I disconnected from the program it automatically logged out. It had never been a problem until I got my new computer.  I will try that.

Comment: It can be configured to log out off automatically however this is not set by default.

Comment: But what if I have an in progress project that I cannot log out of my account on the host, like a video render? Will "Logging out" on the client logout the user (and it's tasks) on the host too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I continued to do research, I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1026423/windows-10-black-screen-after-local-login-and-previous-remote-desktop-session?rq=1) which informed me correctly that disabling nVidia's Shadow Play fixed the issue. (so far)