# Black screen on Windows 10 Remote Desktop after Windows 10 May Update 2019

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-10-upgrade, black-screen-of-death

I always connect to my domain computers using Windows 10 Remote Desktop in version 1809 without any problems.

Now, some computers were upgraded to **Windows 10 1903 May Update 2019 version**. After that, i can connect to those computers, but **it always shows a black screen and i cannot do anything**. CTRL+ALT+END does not work. It shows the mouse icon, so i supose that the session is connected OK, but i cannot do anything or to manually start the explorer. Of course, i cannot see the Desktop.

I followed the steps on: 
[Windows 10 Remote Desktop Connects with Black Screen then Disconnects](https://superuser.com/questions/976290/windows-10-remote-desktop-connects-with-black-screen-then-disconnects) without success.

Anyone have an idea? I would not like to have to go back to the previous version

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Finally solved by using Local Group Policy Editor on the host machine to force the use of the old XDDM display driver. In `Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Remote Session Environment`, set the Policy Use `WDDM graphics display driver for Remote Desktop Connections' from "Not Configured" to "Disabled."

Comment: Note this works with domain GPO as well; but it requires the domain `PolicyDefinitions` to be updated to 1903 (and the [link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/2/0/9200837E-1415-40C0-BE02-BDE308606DC5/Administrative%20Templates%20(.admx)%20for%20Windows%2010%20May%202019%20Update.msi) at [Microsoft Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=58495) is currently down or pulled off).

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been solved by [KB4512941](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4512941)
Detail see: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903#669msgdesc

Answer (score 1):

Thx for this answer for me. 
My problem was for a windows 10 in vmware esxi. 
RDP show a black screen and very very very slow refresh of the desktop and disconnection.
It was because of 3D acceleration (vmware svga 3d driver). 
Just disable 3d in esxi and it works nice.
Harder to do in a real PC...
So this problem is because of display driver, and not network problem like UDP protocole or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the integrated graphics motherboard driver (Q43/Q45 Intel graphics chipset). It was not compatible with Windows 10 1903 Version.

Couldn´t find any driver over the internet to make them work, so had to buy a new graphics card and install it. After that, problems dissapeared

Answer (score -1):

The solution to update/change the graphics driver from the below URL worked for me:

http://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2019/06/remote-desktop-black-screen-in-windows-10-1903-update.html

"...better update the driver manually.
* Right-click the current Graphics item in Device manager, and select “Update driver”. Then click on Browse my computer for driver software > Let me pick from a list of device drivers > Microsoft Basic Display Adapter, and click OK button."